# Converting Decimals to Integers from getValues()

Tags: google-apps-script, converters

I'm ready data from my Google Sheets doc with the following line

```
startRow = 4;
sheet = SpreadSheetApp.getActiveSheet();
data = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,8,23).getValues();
```

I'm looping through these values and want to send them in to Google Analytics as an event value however when I log the values I get for data they come out as decimals, for example, 987.0.

I've formatted the cells so that they don't have any decimal points and have also made sure the data itself contains no decimal points.

Is there anyway that I can convert the values in data from a decimal to an integer?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `parseInt()`.   Docs can be found here:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

```
startRow = 4;
sheet = SpreadSheetApp.getActiveSheet();
data = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,8,23).getValues();
var myInt = parseInt(data[0][0]);
```